# Using window.open(url,"_self") opens download window, but not GET request

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, get

I understand that opening a new window with a URL essentially issues a GET request for that specified URL. I have a URL that when opening using window.open(), a a browser download is triggered. However, when I issue an actual GET request via AJAX, why does the response not trigger a browser download?

Comment: _"However, when I issue an actual GET request via AJAX, why does the response not trigger a browser download?"_ `window.open()` is not called with response as first parameter , `location.href` is not changed to response ? "Save File" dialog is opened when call `window.open()` if window does not handle protocol . What is expected result when response is received from an ajax call ?

Answer (score 1):

You can only trigger browser download by redirecting the browser tab to the download URL, it is not possible to do it using AJAX request.

When the browser (as in: the current URL loaded in the browser's tab) visits a URL, it is the browser's responsibility to handle the response. For file downloads, the appropriate action to handle the response is to show a download dialog. When you perform a GET request through AJAX though, it is *your* responsibility to handle the response, not the browser's. The response may contain any data and most of the time the browser wouldn't even understand what that data means.

---

If what you're trying to achieve is a delayed download start (like SourceForge and others do) or to show you a post-download page then start a download, that can be achieved by redirecting to the post-download page, and starting a Javascript timer there that then redirects the browser (not just AJAX, but the `window.location`) to the download URL. The way browsers usually handle this, the post-download page will remain loaded and you'll get a download dialog.

Comment: so in order to have that AJAX response trigger a download, I have to set some Header types and modify the response? Will this still trigger a download with an appropriate file name if the URL involves query params?

Comment: If you need the AJAX response to trigger download, you'll need to send some kind of response that *your* client Javascript code will interpret as an instruction to trigger a download, and the client Javascript code will have t redirect the whole browser tab to the desired download URL.